# Examples for Burnside problem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, combinatorial-group-theory

What are some examples for Burnside Problem- example of an infinite finitely generated torsion group - except Grigorchuk group.

I have studies Grigorchuk group as an counterexample which was first given to settle this question, but wondering are there other examples. What are they? Any sources to them are welcome. 
Thanks

Comment: There were some examples constructed by Gupta and Sidki, which are similar to the Grigorchuk group, but are based on an odd prime rather than on $2$.

Comment: Tarski Monster group is another example. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group

Comment: An example, based on symmetries of a tree, may be found in John Meier's book, *Groups, Graphs and Trees*. However, the torsion is not uniformely bounded.

Answer (score 6):

In the class of so called automaton groups there are multiple examples, such as the Gupta-Sidki groups (*On the Burnside problem for periodic groups*, 1983) or Brieussel's example (*An automata group of intermediate growth and exponential activity*, Journal of Group Theory) or an other construction of Grigorchuk on larger alphabet leading to p-groups (*Degrees of growth ofp-groups and torsion-free groups*, 1985 ; see also https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0005113.pdf for some generalizations).

Recently, Nekrashevych gave explicit examples of infinite simple torsion groups (which have in addition intermediate growth) *https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.01033.pdf*

In addition, a quick look to the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_problem shows that the Burnside problem was originally solved by Golod and Shafarevich in 1963, and that later Aidan and Novikov proved that, for a (odd) large enough ($>4381$) $m$, there exists groups
$$B(k,m) = \langle a_1, ..., a_k | w^m =\mathbb{1} \:\:\forall w \in \{a_1, ..., a_k\}^*\rangle$$
(i.e. the groups were the m-th power of any word is trivial)
which are infinite.

This has been extended by  Ivanov and Ol'shanskii to the case of even $m$.